# Plotting daily data for a year with X-axis having month name

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-science

I have a series with daily data for a given year. e.g. I have data for the maximum temperature of each day for a year. Each day is represented in format 'Month_Day'. While plotting the series in matplotlib, the x-axis gets darken and nothing appears as shown in the attached figure[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9LrJ.png). I want to plot each day data bu x-axis should have the month name instead. How to set the x-axis with month name?

Comment: Research `matplotlib.dates.MonthLocator`.

Comment: Also convert your strings to dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import MonthLocator, DateFormatter

# Sample data
dates = pd.date_range('2015-01-01', '2015-12-31')
values = np.random.rand(len(dates))
df = pd.DataFrame({"Date": dates,
                   "Value": values})
```

```
>>>
    Date    Value
0   2015-01-01  0.150016
1   2015-01-02  0.565111
2   2015-01-03  0.229569
3   2015-01-04  0.952355
4   2015-01-05  0.509594
```

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(df.Date, df.Value)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MonthLocator())  # Tick locator
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%B'))  # Date format
```